# Laravel 4 - Unable to reference to a namespaced route group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've skimmed through the documentation several times without success, I'm facing the following issue.

I have a form in one of my templates that is trying to generate a url based on a controller method:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'AdminController@togglePerformance']) }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('toggle', 1, PerformanceReport::is_active(),  [
        'class'             => 'switch',
        'data-on-color'     => 'success',
        'data-off-color'    => 'danger']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And the relevant part of my routes.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'members','namespace' => 'Members'], function() {
    //Performance management

    Route::get('admin/performance', 'AdminController@managePerformance');
    Route::post('admin/performance/toggle','AdminController@togglePerformance');
});
```

And the error I'm receiving:

```
Route [AdminController@togglePerformance] not defined. (View: /Users/Tristan/Documents/Web/linkglobal/app/views/members/admin/performance/index.blade.php)
```

My best guess is that I may have to include the namespace in my form, but I'm hoping there's another solution.

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

```
'namespace' => 'Members'
```

And inside it

```
Route::get('admin/performance', 'AdminController@managePerformance');
```

Your route is action should be

```
Members\AdminController@managePerformance
```

So

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'Members\AdminController@togglePerformance']) }}
```